# COUNT function when grouping a union query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

A legacy database has an association class represented as several fields.  Even if the association class doesn't get normalized, I need to standardize the values to remove minor spelling variations.

I want to accumulate all of the values in a single UNION query and would also like to count the number of occurrences.

The query accumulates all of the values, but the count field always comes out as 1 for every value. I see multiple entries of the same value in the table.

The problem here could be MS Access because it appears from other Stackoverflow entries that this works in other flavors of SQL.

```
SELECT [Allofem].Keyword, Count(*) as Occurrences
FROM
(
 SELECT Keyword1 as Keyword
 FROM srctab    
 WHERE (Keyword1 Is Not Null And Keyword1<>"")

 UNION
 SELECT Keyword2 as  Keyword
 FROM srctab    
 WHERE (Keyword2 Is Not Null And Keyword2<>"")

 UNION
 SELECT Keyword3 as  Keyword
 FROM srctab
 WHERE (Keyword3 Is Not Null And Keyword3<>"")

 UNION
 SELECT Keyword4 as Keyword
 FROM srctab
 WHERE (Keyword4 Is Not Null And Keyword4<>"")

 UNION
 SELECT Keyword5 as  Keyword
 FROM srctab
 WHERE (Keyword5 Is Not Null And Keyword5<>"")

 UNION
 SELECT Keyword6 as  Keyword
 FROM srctab
 WHERE (Keyword6 Is Not Null And Keyword6<>"")
)  AS [Allofem]
GROUP BY [Allofem].Keyword
ORDER BY [Allofem].Keyword;
```

Update: There is something seriously weird going on here, because there are more records when you select only one keyword field (i.e. no UNION) than when it's UNIONED with another keyword field's selection.

Comment: Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. `UNION` acts as a `GROUP BY` which is definitely not what you want in this case.

Comment: When in doubt, run your subqueries by their lonesome. It will make problems like this one immediately apparent.